# Estimate the variance of a population given only the means of independent subpopulations

Tags: variance

Given a set of independent samples $x_{i,j}$ where $i$ ranges from 1 to $m$ and $j$ ranges from 1 to $n$, it is easy to estimate the variance of the underlying distribution using a formula like
\begin{equation}
\text{Var}(x) = \sum_{i,j} x_{i,j}^2 - (\sum_{i,j} x_{i,j})^2.
\end{equation}
Unfortunately, I need to estimate this variance without directly measuring the $x_{i,j}$.  Instead, I only have access to the set of "sub-population means"
\begin{equation}
y_i = \frac1n\sum_{j=1}^nx_{i,j}.
\end{equation}
It's easy to see that $\text{Var}(y)$ is an underestimate of $\text{Var}(x)$ using arguments based on the law of large numbers or jensen's inquality.  So how can I get an unbiased estimate the variance of the $x$s given only the $y$s?

Answer (score 1):

We can easily compute the variance of $y$ as
$$\operatorname{Var}(y_i) = \operatorname{Var}(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n x_{ij}) = \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{j=1}^n\operatorname{Var}(x_{ij})= \frac{1}{n}\operatorname{Var}(x_{ij}).$$
Thus if $\hat{y}$ is any unbiased estimator of $\operatorname{Var}(y)$, then $n\cdot \hat{y}$ is an unbiased estimator of $\operatorname{Var}(x)$.

Comment: Your final formula is intuitively basically what I think the answer should be, but I don't follow where your middle equality comes from.  For the particular case of $n=1$ and $m$ large, I don't think it's correct.  In this case, we have  $\text{Var}(y_i) = 0$; because there's only one value, there's no variance.  But then your estimator for $\text{Var}(x_{i,j})$ is also always 0, which is clearly incorrect.

Comment: From basic probability theory we have for random variables $X$ and $Y$, that $Var(a\cdot X) = a^2\cdot Var(X)$ (for any constant $a$) and that $Var(X+Y) = Var(X) + Var(Y) + 2Cov(X,Y)$, where $Cov(X,Y)=0$ when $X$ and $Y$ are independent. This should explain the middle equality.

Comment: A single observation does not necessarily have $0$ variance. For instance a single observation from a $N(0,4)$ distribution would have variance $4$, however, there is (usually) no way to estimate the variance from a single observation. My computation holds regardless of what $m$ and $n$ is, but it requires that an unbiased estimator of $Var(y)$ exists. The usual estimator would be
$$\hat{y} = \frac{1}{m-1} \sum_{i=1}^m (y_i - \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^m y_i)^2,$$
which of course fails to exist when $m=1$.